# Separating declaration and implementation in free pascal

Tags: freepascal, delphi

I'm working on a networking application where messages are passed between the clients and the server.  The message type declarations are the same for both the client and the server.  E.g., a message may look like this:

```
TExampleMessage = class(TObject)
public
  ProcessId: Word;
  procedure Execute(Sender: TObject);
end;
```

However, how the messages behave (the contents of the Execute procedure) varies significantly between processes.

What I've done so far is to simply have a unit of messages for the client and another for the server.  I would like to be able to combine the two in some way so that I can have all of the types declared in one shared unit and the actual implementation of the message behavior implemented in units tied to the process.

Is this possible?  And if it is possible, is it worth doing?

Comment: Perhaps using Interfaces? One unit with interfaces, and two units (server/client) for the implementation of those interfaces.

Comment: I've thought about that.  All of the messages right now share a lot of the same methods, so an interface would make sense.  At some point I would also like to have a shared message factory, would interfaces allow for that?

Comment: Well I'm not familiar with freepascal in particular, but I suppose it *should* be possible. A personal preference of mine however is to keep things in a JSON object.

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you use JSON for transmitting data back and forth or do your programs act on JSON objects?

Comment: Both. But only when I'm transmitting and/or receiving it. I just keep it and use it in that format. Saves on performance of parsing / serializing.

Comment: Of course it's possible. Are your client and server both using "classes" for instance? They might as well both use "netmessages". Of course it's worth doing, you'd maintain base classes in one place.

Comment: Yes, they're both using classes.  Is netmessages a package or is it just an example that names don't really matter?

Comment: @Greg - It's the unit that would contain TBaseMesage, TServerMessage, TClientMessage etc.. Of course you can name it differently. :)

Comment: @JerryDodge does that require frequent serialization/unserialization?

Comment: Only when you need to transition between the two. Data is received, for example, in plain JSON format. In any case, you have to parse it into an object structure. Once it's in that structure, I just keep it there. Changing data doesn't reserialize it, until the moment you wish to convert it back into plain JSON. Dumping it into another object structure just adds a little more of a load. However, I do also practice wrapping that JSON object inside another, and expose properties to read/write the data. But I see it a waste to copy all that data.

Answer (score 1):

looks like i don't understand something, but why you don't use standard OOP approach? declare TSampleMsg object with virtual/abstract Execute method and derive different classes from it overriding this method?

Comment: Hm. Well actually I did, but I guess based on my drowsiness I did so in a profoundly silly manner.  I have two base classes: `TServerMessage` and `TClientMessage`.  `TExampleMessage` would derive from either `TServerMessage` or `TClientMessage`, depending on the implementation.  What I probably should be doing is setting up `TExampleMessage` in a shared unit and have `TServerExampleMessage` and `TClientExampleMessage` be derivative classes.

Comment: Exactly. for example, whenever you have to call method, passing either TServerMsg or TClientMsg as a parameter, you will declare it like

Comment: .. 

    procedure MyProc (Msg: TExampleMsg);
    begin
      Msg.Execute();
    end;

and every instance will execute it's own implementation of Execute method. isn't it what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's largely the goal.

Comment: Why two base classes? Why not one abstract base class (`TBaseMessage`) from which `TServerMessage` and `TClientMessage` derive?